# How to hide the y axis on the Kendo Chart?

Tags: kendo-ui

[image]

As shown in the image, I have the y-axis with the labels in it

```
 valueAxis: {
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: true
                },
                labels: {
                    template: "#= kendo.format('{0}',value/1000)#K"
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Steps",
                    font: "14px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"
                }
            }
```

I want the labels to remain , but hide the axis line. Is it possible in Kendo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out

```
 valueAxis: {
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: true
                },
                line: {
                    visible:false
                },

                labels: {
                    template: "#= kendo.format('{0}',value/1000)#K"
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Steps",
                    font: "14px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"
                }
            }
```